# Ajax alert box is showing HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery AJAX to call a parameterised function on dynamic button click. Script and function is working fine. only problem is, it is showing all the HTML code into alert box. right from . I don't need to show HTML code, only need to show successfull messages. Please someone help me. Thanks

```
<html>
    tables, textbox, buttons
</html>

<?php

//some php, sql stuff

    echo "<td><input type='button' name='disable' value='Disable' onClick='disable($id);'/></td>";

?>

<script>
    function disable(id) { 
        jQuery.ajax({   type: 'Post', 
                    url: '', 
                    data: {action: 'delete', ID: id} 
        })
        .done(function(data) { 
           alert("Data Saved: " + data); 
            location.reload();
        }); 
    }

</script>
```

Alert box is showing html code in HTML block and successful messages from php block. I don't need to show HTML code, only need to show successful messages.

Comment: data is the result from the url where you post to , it can include some html tags

Comment: I think you need data.responseText - not sure with jQuery though

Comment: data is whatever ur echoing in the executed php script

Comment: My code file is like this:-- <html> table, text box etc </html> <?php --- php and html code ---?> <script> AJAX script </script> actually I am getting all table and text box tags/code from <html> part. I want show only 'successful' message from php block

Comment: i hope you have a url in the ajax?

Comment: @madalin ivascu Yes I have url field in ajax but i passed blank

Comment: you mean you ajaxing to the same page?why?

Comment: @madalin ivascu : I have edited the code in my question. I am new to PHP and AJAX. and working on these things in WordPress.

Comment: you need 2 files one for the php one for the ajax

Comment: Do I need to use JSON encode if I wish to ajaxing to the same page???

Answer (score 0):

I often use this scheme.
I do in php

```
echo "response_ok";
```

And in javascript i test if php responded with ok this way:

```
$.get("checkfornew.php", function(data, status)
    {
        if ( data.indexOf("response_ok") != -1)
        {
              //response contains "response_ok" string
        }
   });
```

Also if you want to display the response from php without html tags you can strip html tags from javascript.But I just display a "response_ok" message from php , and if javascript receive this response it show a html that is already but hidden in the html page.